# Help me understand about the calculation of the Dominium in a function (?)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

[image: Italian mathematics]

I really don't understand why the argument of the natural logarithm is greater than or equal to one. I don't know if this question sounds stupid, and I apologize in that case, but I am very new to funcions, so I am wondering if someone can explain me this passage here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Per risolvere $\log (x+2) \ge 0$, basta che prendi gli esponenziali e ottieni $e^{ \log (x+2)} \ge e^0$, cioè $x+2 \ge 1$.

Comment: Grazie mille! Non pensavo fosse così semplice il passaggio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Crostul* explains it well (in Italian), but for anyone not being able to decipher it, it is roughly:

If we have $\ln(t) \geq 0$, it follows (from exponentiating both sides) that $$e^{\ln(t)}=t\geq e^0=1$$

Comment: Yes well done to both of you, thanks a lot!